# Symfony 3 OneUp Flysystem error: There is no extension able to load the configuration for "oneup_flysystem"

Tags: php, symfony, flysystem

According to the [configuration](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupFlysystemBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/filesystem_create.md) of Flysystem i have put the following settings on my config.yml:

```
oneup_flysystem:
    adapters:
        acme.flysystem_adapter:
            awss3v3:
                client: acme.s3_client
                bucket: "%s3_bucket_name%"
                prefix: "symfotest_"
```

And I have provided the following settings on services.yml:

```
acme.s3_client:
        class: Aws\S3\S3Client
        arguments:
            -
                version: 'latest' # or 'latest'
                region: "%s3_region%" # 'eu-central-1' for example
                credentials:
                    key: "%s3_key%"
                    secret: "%s3_secret%"
```

End I have set the following enviromental variables via SetEnv:

```
SetEnv SYMFONY_S3_BUCKET_NAME   symphotest
SetEnv SYMFONY_S3_REGION    eu_west_1
SetEnv SYMFONY_S3_KEY       akey 
SetEnv SYMFONY_S3_SECRET    asuperseccret
```

But I get the following error on my error.log:

> [Wed Jul 06 21:11:56.424801 2016] [:error] [pid 21876] [client
>   127.0.0.1:60488] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException:
>   There is no extension able to load the configuration for
>   "oneup_flysystem" (in
>   /home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/web/apps/symphotest/app/config/config.yml).
>   Looked for namespace "oneup_flysystem", found "framework", "security",
>   "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "doctrine", "sensio_framework_extra"
>   in
>   /home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/web/apps/symphotest/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php:368\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/web/apps/symphotest/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php(338):
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader->validate(Array,
>   '/home/pcmagas/K...')\n#1
>   /home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/web/apps/symphotest/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php(44):
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader->loadFile('/home/pcmagas/K...')\n#2
>   /home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/we in
>   /home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/web/apps/symphotest/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Loader/FileLoader.php
>   on line 118

Do you have any Idea hos is this fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens when the OneUpBundle is not registered in the AppKernel. Add the corresponding bundle class to the other bundles in the `registerBundles` method and you should be golden.

For more information look [here](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupFlysystemBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md)